# Exposed Filters in Entity Type Reference

Tags: entities

I have used and entity reference field in my content type Showrooms. The field references to another content type Cars.

Cars has a category field attached to it such as audi, mercedes, bmw etc. Each car has once category only. Now what i want is that the user can filter the cars on category. I have used a reference field, but it lists all the cars. I want the user to be able to filter it.

Should work some thing like this, the user first chooses the category and then from the other drop down should choose a car and that car should be referenced.

Answer (score 1):

you can put your car categories in a taxomomy list and then use [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) to filter the way you asked. quite straightforward.

Comment: I have tried doing so, but then it does not pull the cars in that category. or I can say i do not know how to do it.

Comment: Also it is not a view, where user can filter. It is a reference entity. When the user is adding a showroom he can be able to reference cars. But i need these cars to be filtered. Please guide if you know any workaround.

Comment: here's the  complete [how to](http://drupal.org/node/968712)